# Physijs where to read about functions?

Tags: three.js, physijs

Can't understand where to know what physijs functions do. There are many functions like applyImpulse, applyForce etc. but there is no documentation for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Physi.js` is a wrapper for `ammo.js` which is a port of `bullet`. I dont know of any good guides/tutorials for physi.js or ammo.js that covers more than a basic scene. However when you want to learn about what the functions are doing, you can look it up in the bullet physics docs.

What helped me understand were some bullet tutorials here: http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Tutorial_Articles

and the Forum where you can find further information in some user posts: http://www.bulletphysics.org/Bullet/phpBB3/index.php?sid=0e8c6e5111583be0d17f1731e4c1dc19

Comment: Thanks, though started to work with unreal engine 4 ) I think if you have idea you can do your things there faster then tricking with js.

Comment: I did a project with UE4 also, getting started with templates and Assets from the store is super fast! First/Third Person Template, Collisions, Physics, Multiplayer, Animations, etc. :-) ```Three.js``` sadly does not want to be a game-engine or even a framework.